# jQuery.bind unbind, multiples instances of classes

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements with the same class "clickable", i'm binding all these classes with:

```
 $('.clickable').bind('click', function()
     { 
       $(this.id).html('clicked');

     }
```

I'm assuming the bind binds each element with the class "clickable" individually.
Then within this bind-function, I want to unbind the currently clicked element with:

```
 $(this.id).unbind('click');
```

So that if you click again within this element, it doesn't trigger the click-function again.
And then, after doing stuff within the element (replace the text withing these elements with an  that puts the current text in it, and when you click outside it it wil alter the html for it) I want to rebind the click again, but I cant't seem to unbind the click for this.id...

Some fiddle for clarification:
http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/QZMP6/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because your selector is wrong (because your selector would translate to something like `$("my_id")` when you really want `$("#my_id")`). In this case, you could just do:

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

Which is ultimately better than querying the DOM again for an element.

*Side note*: `bind` and `unbind` are deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. The updated way to write this is with `on` and `off`:

```
$(".clickable").on("click", function () {
    /* ... */
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

*Edit* (per comments below):

If you want to prevent parent event handlers from being notified as well, you could bind a new handler that prevents propagation of the event:

```
$(this).off("click").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @Gasman, if you wanted to use the id, you'd have to include `#` in front, like `$('#' + this.id)`. Of course, there's no reason you'd do this when you can just do `$(this)`, but I figured I'd point out the specific place you got the selector wrong.

Comment: @BenLee: Thanks--I've updated my answer to include your comment

Comment: @Andrew: The docs don't list `bind/unbind` as officially deprecated, but it certainly does describe `on/off` as *"preferred"*.

Comment: If I do this, It seems to react to the parents' click event, but I'm trying to prevent this, I tried unbinding it and rebinding it to an empty function, but no cake.. (I'm not sure if this is because the elements are transparent?)

Comment: Thing is, the encapsulating elements which contain the elements are also bound to the clicks, this is inherent to what I want, but I don't understand why the click event seems to go straight through the actual clicked element...

Comment: Check out my updated answer. You need to stop the propagation of the click event so that parent event handlers aren't notified.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/QZMP6/7/ for clarification, but your update seems to have helped anyways..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider jQuery's selector based event delegation, and just remove the `'clickable'` class when clicked...

```
$('body').on('click', '.clickable', function() { 
    $(this).html('clicked')
           .removeClass('clickable');
});
```

Or in pre-jQuery 1.7, but post 1.4 or so...

```
$('body').delegate('.clickable', 'click', function() { 
    $(this).html('clicked')
           .removeClass('clickable');
});
```

In both cases, I placed the delegate handler on the `'body'`, but it would be better to place it on a more local element, as long as it encompasses all the `.clickable` elements.