# Passing events to external function

Tags: this, jquery

Fiddle me this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/QZMP6/17/

After editing the input field, the html updates on each element, but I want to reenable/restore the click event..

I tried making the click event an external function, but I can't seem to get the 'this' to work properly/communicate with the function...

Can't seem to find good explanations how to pass events to functions...

As you can see in the fiddle, I try to do:

```
$(this).on("click");
```

But off-course it defines nothing so it won't work, so I'll have to re-call/re-assign the whole function.?

Comment: If you want to enable/disable handlers, you should look at [the answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9103128/1106925) to your previous question. Using that technique, it's as simple as adding/removing a the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function as a variable. That way you can just reference it in the click handler by its variable name:

http://jsfiddle.net/QZMP6/25/

```
var clicky = function()
{
    var currentClickedDIV = this.id;
        $('#output').append("Clicked: "+currentClickedDIV +"<BR>");   
    var currentClickedDIVContent = $(this).html();
        $('#output').append("HTML: "+currentClickedDIVContent +"<BR>" );  

   //Make current html content editable
   $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html("<INPUT id='currentInput' value='"+currentClickedDIVContent+"'></INPUT>");

     //prevent more triggers within element       
   $(this).off("click").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    //Focus cursor on input
    $("#currentInput").focus();

    var $that = $(this);
    //On blur replace with plain html, also reenable click?
    $("#currentInput").blur(function(){
        var currInput = $("#currentInput").val();
        $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html(currInput );
        $('#output').append("New HTML: "+ currInput  +"<BR>" );
        $that.on("click", clicky);
    });


    return false;
}

$('.cuboid').on('click', clicky );
```

Comment: Make sure to use the `var` statement when creating variables. If you don't then all the variables become global variables.

Comment: Mistake, sorry. Amended my answer.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need, and off-course 'this' is still 'this' so no need to pass it I guess...

Comment: Yes, just make sure your second reference to this is correct since scope changes there, which is why I set it to `$that`.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZMP6/23/

If you change this:

```
   //Make current html content editable
   $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html("<INPUT id='currentInput' value='"+currentClickedDIVContent+"'></INPUT>");
```

to this:

```
   //Make current html content editable
   $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html("<INPUT id='currentInput' value='"+currentClickedDIVContent+"'></INPUT>").children().on('blur', function () {
        $('#' + currentClickedDIV).off('click').on('click', external_click);
    });
```

The event handler will be re-attached after the input element is `blur`ed. Also notice I moved your code into an external function named `external_click`. Here is the code from the demo posted above:

```
function external_click() {
        var currentClickedDIV = this.id;
            $('#output').append("Clicked: "+currentClickedDIV +"<BR>");   
        var currentClickedDIVContent = $(this).html();
            $('#output').append("HTML: "+currentClickedDIVContent +"<BR>" );  

       //Make current html content editable
       $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html("<INPUT id='currentInput' value='"+currentClickedDIVContent+"'></INPUT>").children().on('blur', function () {
            $('#' + currentClickedDIV).off('click').on('click', external_click);
        });

        //Focus cursor on input
        $("#currentInput").focus();

        //On blur replace with plain html, also reenable click?
        $("#currentInput").blur(function(){
            var currInput = $("#currentInput").val();
            $("#"+currentClickedDIV).html(currInput );
            $('#output').append("New HTML: "+ currInput  +"<BR>" );
        });


        //prevent more triggers within element
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).off("click").on("click", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        return false;
    }
$('.cuboid').on('click', external_click);
```